# How to build IronPython3?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ironpython

I want to use [IronPython3](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3) within my C# application. Because it is still in development, there is no build referenced on the GitHub site. SO you have to build it on your own.

It is stated, that you have to run `make` command in a Visual Studio prompt. I've tried that from outside and within Visual Studio, but it is not a valid command, it says.

Building the solution itself works fine. But I'm not sure which DLL's and other files I have to use afterward.

I guess the `make` command will call the `make.cmd` file. If I execute that file I receive the following error:

> **Error MSB4041:** The default XML namespace of the project must be the
>   MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
>   format, please add
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>   element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2
>   format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

After adding that XML namespace manually, the **warning MSB4078** appears.

So my question is, can I just use the compiled DLLs the build action of VS2017 gives me? Or do I have to go deeper to fix this errors somehow (which could be a pain me for)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the developers on their [gitter](https://gitter.im/IronLanguages/ironpython) chat room and got the answer, that IronPyton 3 is not usable at the moment. And it'll probably take some time, until it will be.